# error: illegal start of expression void inputInfo();

Tags: java

I know questions like this have been answered before but I cannot seem to find any semicolons missing. So, what is wrong with my code guys? please help.

My assignment is : Develop a Java application to calculate the monthly paychecks for a number of different types of employees. The employee types are created in a subclass array based on parent base class Employee.  Initial code is provided for each class and for a driver class. Below is what I have for the main class. When I put the inputInfo method outside of main and then try to use it i get a ton of error messages such as:

```
error: cannot find symbol
      earnings = input.nextDouble();
      ^
  symbol:   variable earnings
  location: class PayrollSystemTest
PayrollSystemTest.java:68: error: cannot find symbol
      earnings = input.nextDouble();
                 ^
  symbol:   variable input
  location: class PayrollSystemTest
PayrollSystemTest.java:69: error: cannot find symbol
      dob = new Date(month, day, year);
      ^
  symbol:   variable dob
  location: class PayrollSystemTest
PayrollSystemTest.java:69: error: cannot find symbol
      dob = new Date(month, day, year);
                     ^
  symbol:   variable month
  location: class PayrollSystemTest
PayrollSystemTest.java:69: error: cannot find symbol
      dob = new Date(month, day, year);
                            ^
  symbol:   variable day
  location: class PayrollSystemTest
PayrollSystemTest.java:69: error: cannot find symbol
      dob = new Date(month, day, year);
                                 ^
  symbol:   variable year
  location: class PayrollSystemTest
PayrollSystemTest.java:70: error: cannot find symbol
      SalariedEmployee salariedEmployee1 = new SalariedEmployee(firstName, lastName, socialNum, dob, earnings);
                                                                ^
  symbol:   variable firstName
  location: class PayrollSystemTest
PayrollSystemTest.java:70: error: cannot find symbol
      SalariedEmployee salariedEmployee1 = new SalariedEmployee(firstName, lastName, socialNum, dob, earnings);
                                                                           ^
  symbol:   variable lastName
  location: class PayrollSystemTest
PayrollSystemTest.java:70: error: cannot find symbol
      SalariedEmployee salariedEmployee1 = new SalariedEmployee(firstName, lastName, socialNum, dob, earnings);
                                                                                     ^
  symbol:   variable socialNum
  location: class PayrollSystemTest
PayrollSystemTest.java:70: error: cannot find symbol
      SalariedEmployee salariedEmployee1 = new SalariedEmployee(firstName, lastName, socialNum, dob, earnings);
                                                                                                ^
  symbol:   variable dob
  location: class PayrollSystemTest
PayrollSystemTest.java:70: error: cannot find symbol
      SalariedEmployee salariedEmployee1 = new SalariedEmployee(firstName, lastName, socialNum, dob, earnings);
                                                                                                     ^
  symbol:   variable earnings
  location: class PayrollSystemTest
PayrollSystemTest.java:75: error: cannot find symbol
      earnings = input.nextDouble();
      ^
  symbol:   variable earnings
  location: class PayrollSystemTest
PayrollSystemTest.java:75: error: cannot find symbol
      earnings = input.nextDouble();
                 ^
  symbol:   variable input
  location: class PayrollSystemTest
PayrollSystemTest.java:76: error: cannot find symbol
      dob = new Date(month, day, year);
      ^
  symbol:   variable dob
  location: class PayrollSystemTest
PayrollSystemTest.java:76: error: cannot find symbol
      dob = new Date(month, day, year);
                     ^
  symbol:   variable month
  location: class PayrollSystemTest
PayrollSystemTest.java:76: error: cannot find symbol
      dob = new Date(month, day, year);
                            ^
  symbol:   variable day
  location: class PayrollSystemTest
PayrollSystemTest.java:76: error: cannot find symbol
      dob = new Date(month, day, year);
                                 ^
  symbol:   variable year
  location: class PayrollSystemTest
PayrollSystemTest.java:77: error: cannot find symbol
      SalariedEmployee salariedEmployee2 = new SalariedEmployee(firstName, lastName, socialNum, dob, earnings);
                                                                ^
  symbol:   variable firstName
  location: class PayrollSystemTest
PayrollSystemTest.java:77: error: cannot find symbol
      SalariedEmployee salariedEmployee2 = new SalariedEmployee(firstName, lastName, socialNum, dob, earnings);
                                                                           ^
  symbol:   variable lastName
  location: class PayrollSystemTest
PayrollSystemTest.java:77: error: cannot find symbol
      SalariedEmployee salariedEmployee2 = new SalariedEmployee(firstName, lastName, socialNum, dob, earnings);
                                                                                     ^
  symbol:   variable socialNum
  location: class PayrollSystemTest
PayrollSystemTest.java:77: error: cannot find symbol
      SalariedEmployee salariedEmployee2 = new SalariedEmployee(firstName, lastName, socialNum, dob, earnings);
                                                                                                ^
  symbol:   variable dob
  location: class PayrollSystemTest
PayrollSystemTest.java:77: error: cannot find symbol
      SalariedEmployee salariedEmployee2 = new SalariedEmployee(firstName, lastName, socialNum, dob, earnings);
                                                                                                     ^
  symbol:   variable earnings
  location: class PayrollSystemTest
PayrollSystemTest.java:82: error: cannot find symbol
      grossSales = input.nextDouble();
      ^
  symbol:   variable grossSales
  location: class PayrollSystemTest
PayrollSystemTest.java:82: error: cannot find symbol
      grossSales = input.nextDouble();
                   ^
  symbol:   variable input
  location: class PayrollSystemTest
PayrollSystemTest.java:84: error: cannot find symbol
      commissionRate = input.nextDouble();
      ^
  symbol:   variable commissionRate
  location: class PayrollSystemTest
PayrollSystemTest.java:84: error: cannot find symbol
      commissionRate = input.nextDouble();
                       ^
  symbol:   variable input
  location: class PayrollSystemTest
PayrollSystemTest.java:85: error: cannot find symbol
      dob = new Date(month, day, year);
      ^
  symbol:   variable dob
  location: class PayrollSystemTest
PayrollSystemTest.java:85: error: cannot find symbol
      dob = new Date(month, day, year);
                     ^
  symbol:   variable month
  location: class PayrollSystemTest
PayrollSystemTest.java:85: error: cannot find symbol
      dob = new Date(month, day, year);
                            ^
  symbol:   variable day
  location: class PayrollSystemTest
PayrollSystemTest.java:85: error: cannot find symbol
      dob = new Date(month, day, year);
                                 ^
  symbol:   variable year
  location: class PayrollSystemTest
PayrollSystemTest.java:86: error: cannot find symbol
      CommissionEmployee commissionEmployee = new CommissonEmployee(firstName, lastName, socialNum, dob, grossSales, commissonRate);
                                                  ^
  symbol:   class CommissonEmployee
  location: class PayrollSystemTest
PayrollSystemTest.java:86: error: cannot find symbol
      CommissionEmployee commissionEmployee = new CommissonEmployee(firstName, lastName, socialNum, dob, grossSales, commissonRate);
                                                                    ^
  symbol:   variable firstName
  location: class PayrollSystemTest
PayrollSystemTest.java:86: error: cannot find symbol
      CommissionEmployee commissionEmployee = new CommissonEmployee(firstName, lastName, socialNum, dob, grossSales, commissonRate);
                                                                               ^
  symbol:   variable lastName
  location: class PayrollSystemTest
PayrollSystemTest.java:86: error: cannot find symbol
      CommissionEmployee commissionEmployee = new CommissonEmployee(firstName, lastName, socialNum, dob, grossSales, commissonRate);
                                                                                         ^
  symbol:   variable socialNum
  location: class PayrollSystemTest
PayrollSystemTest.java:86: error: cannot find symbol
      CommissionEmployee commissionEmployee = new CommissonEmployee(firstName, lastName, socialNum, dob, grossSales, commissonRate);
                                                                                                    ^
  symbol:   variable dob
  location: class PayrollSystemTest
PayrollSystemTest.java:86: error: cannot find symbol
      CommissionEmployee commissionEmployee = new CommissonEmployee(firstName, lastName, socialNum, dob, grossSales, commissonRate);
                                                                                                         ^
  symbol:   variable grossSales
  location: class PayrollSystemTest
PayrollSystemTest.java:86: error: cannot find symbol
      CommissionEmployee commissionEmployee = new CommissonEmployee(firstName, lastName, socialNum, dob, grossSales, commissonRate);
                                                                                                                     ^
  symbol:   variable commissonRate
  location: class PayrollSystemTest
PayrollSystemTest.java:91: error: cannot find symbol
      grossSales = input.nextDouble();
      ^
  symbol:   variable grossSales
  location: class PayrollSystemTest
PayrollSystemTest.java:91: error: cannot find symbol
      grossSales = input.nextDouble();
                   ^
  symbol:   variable input
  location: class PayrollSystemTest
PayrollSystemTest.java:93: error: cannot find symbol
      commissionRate = input.nextDouble();
      ^
  symbol:   variable commissionRate
  location: class PayrollSystemTest
PayrollSystemTest.java:93: error: cannot find symbol
      commissionRate = input.nextDouble();
                       ^
  symbol:   variable input
  location: class PayrollSystemTest
PayrollSystemTest.java:95: error: cannot find symbol
      baseSalary = input.nextDouble();
      ^
  symbol:   variable baseSalary
  location: class PayrollSystemTest
PayrollSystemTest.java:95: error: cannot find symbol
      baseSalary = input.nextDouble();
                   ^
  symbol:   variable input
  location: class PayrollSystemTest
PayrollSystemTest.java:96: error: cannot find symbol
      dob = new Date(month, day, year);
      ^
  symbol:   variable dob
  location: class PayrollSystemTest
PayrollSystemTest.java:96: error: cannot find symbol
      dob = new Date(month, day, year);
                     ^
  symbol:   variable month
  location: class PayrollSystemTest
PayrollSystemTest.java:96: error: cannot find symbol
      dob = new Date(month, day, year);
                            ^
  symbol:   variable day
  location: class PayrollSystemTest
PayrollSystemTest.java:96: error: cannot find symbol
      dob = new Date(month, day, year);
                                 ^
  symbol:   variable year
  location: class PayrollSystemTest
PayrollSystemTest.java:97: error: cannot find symbol
      BasePlusCommissionEmployee basePlusCommissionEmployee = new BasePlusCommissionEmployee(firstName, lastName, socialNum, dob, grossSales, commissionRate, baseSalary);
                                                                                             ^
  symbol:   variable firstName
  location: class PayrollSystemTest
PayrollSystemTest.java:97: error: cannot find symbol
      BasePlusCommissionEmployee basePlusCommissionEmployee = new BasePlusCommissionEmployee(firstName, lastName, socialNum, dob, grossSales, commissionRate, baseSalary);
                                                                                                        ^
  symbol:   variable lastName
  location: class PayrollSystemTest
PayrollSystemTest.java:97: error: cannot find symbol
      BasePlusCommissionEmployee basePlusCommissionEmployee = new BasePlusCommissionEmployee(firstName, lastName, socialNum, dob, grossSales, commissionRate, baseSalary);
                                                                                                                  ^
  symbol:   variable socialNum
  location: class PayrollSystemTest
PayrollSystemTest.java:97: error: cannot find symbol
      BasePlusCommissionEmployee basePlusCommissionEmployee = new BasePlusCommissionEmployee(firstName, lastName, socialNum, dob, grossSales, commissionRate, baseSalary);
                                                                                                                             ^
  symbol:   variable dob
  location: class PayrollSystemTest
PayrollSystemTest.java:97: error: cannot find symbol
      BasePlusCommissionEmployee basePlusCommissionEmployee = new BasePlusCommissionEmployee(firstName, lastName, socialNum, dob, grossSales, commissionRate, baseSalary);
                                                                                                                                  ^
  symbol:   variable grossSales
  location: class PayrollSystemTest
PayrollSystemTest.java:97: error: cannot find symbol
      BasePlusCommissionEmployee basePlusCommissionEmployee = new BasePlusCommissionEmployee(firstName, lastName, socialNum, dob, grossSales, commissionRate, baseSalary);
                                                                                                                                              ^
  symbol:   variable commissionRate
  location: class PayrollSystemTest
PayrollSystemTest.java:97: error: cannot find symbol
      BasePlusCommissionEmployee basePlusCommissionEmployee = new BasePlusCommissionEmployee(firstName, lastName, socialNum, dob, grossSales, commissionRate, baseSalary);
                                                                                                                                                              ^
  symbol:   variable baseSalary
  location: class PayrollSystemTest
PayrollSystemTest.java:102: error: cannot find symbol
      wage = input.nextDouble();
      ^
  symbol:   variable wage
  location: class PayrollSystemTest
PayrollSystemTest.java:102: error: cannot find symbol
      wage = input.nextDouble();
             ^
  symbol:   variable input
  location: class PayrollSystemTest
PayrollSystemTest.java:104: error: cannot find symbol
      hours = input.nextDouble();
      ^
  symbol:   variable hours
  location: class PayrollSystemTest
PayrollSystemTest.java:104: error: cannot find symbol
      hours = input.nextDouble();
              ^
  symbol:   variable input
  location: class PayrollSystemTest
PayrollSystemTest.java:105: error: cannot find symbol
      dob = new Date(month, day, year);
      ^
  symbol:   variable dob
  location: class PayrollSystemTest
PayrollSystemTest.java:105: error: cannot find symbol
      dob = new Date(month, day, year);
                     ^
  symbol:   variable month
  location: class PayrollSystemTest
PayrollSystemTest.java:105: error: cannot find symbol
      dob = new Date(month, day, year);
                            ^
  symbol:   variable day
  location: class PayrollSystemTest
PayrollSystemTest.java:105: error: cannot find symbol
      dob = new Date(month, day, year);
                                 ^
  symbol:   variable year
  location: class PayrollSystemTest
PayrollSystemTest.java:106: error: cannot find symbol
      HourlyEmployee hourlyEmployee = new HourlyEmployee(firstName, lastName, socialNum, dob, wage, hours);
                                                         ^
  symbol:   variable firstName
  location: class PayrollSystemTest
PayrollSystemTest.java:106: error: cannot find symbol
      HourlyEmployee hourlyEmployee = new HourlyEmployee(firstName, lastName, socialNum, dob, wage, hours);
                                                                    ^
  symbol:   variable lastName
  location: class PayrollSystemTest
PayrollSystemTest.java:106: error: cannot find symbol
      HourlyEmployee hourlyEmployee = new HourlyEmployee(firstName, lastName, socialNum, dob, wage, hours);
                                                                              ^
  symbol:   variable socialNum
  location: class PayrollSystemTest
PayrollSystemTest.java:106: error: cannot find symbol
      HourlyEmployee hourlyEmployee = new HourlyEmployee(firstName, lastName, socialNum, dob, wage, hours);
                                                                                         ^
  symbol:   variable dob
  location: class PayrollSystemTest
PayrollSystemTest.java:106: error: cannot find symbol
      HourlyEmployee hourlyEmployee = new HourlyEmployee(firstName, lastName, socialNum, dob, wage, hours);
                                                                                              ^
  symbol:   variable wage
  location: class PayrollSystemTest
PayrollSystemTest.java:106: error: cannot find symbol
      HourlyEmployee hourlyEmployee = new HourlyEmployee(firstName, lastName, socialNum, dob, wage, hours);
                                                                                                    ^
  symbol:   variable hours
  location: class PayrollSystemTest
PayrollSystemTest.java:150: error: cannot find symbol
            CommissionEmployee employee = (CommissonEmployee) currentEmployee;
                                           ^
  symbol:   class CommissonEmployee
  location: class PayrollSystemTest
69 errors

 ----jGRASP wedge2: exit code for process is 1.
 ----jGRASP: operation complete.
```

Here's my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PayrollSystemTest
{

    public static void main( String args[] )
    {

        Employee employees[] = new Employee[ 5 ];
        int i = 0;
        inputInfo();
        System.out.print("What are the earnings of the salaried 
                employee?");
        earnings = input.nextDouble();
        dob = new Date(month, day, year);
        SalariedEmployee salariedEmployee1 = new 
            SalariedEmployee(firstName, lastName, socialNum, dob, 
                    earnings);
        employees[i] = salariedEmployee1; i++;

        inputInfo();
        System.out.print("What are the earnings of the next salaried 
                employee?");
        earnings = input.nextDouble();
        dob = new Date(month, day, year);
        SalariedEmployee salariedEmployee2 = new 
            SalariedEmployee(firstName, lastName, socialNum, dob, 
                    earnings);
        employees[i] = salariedEmployee2; i++;

        inputInfo();
        System.out.print("What are the gross sales of the commission 
                employee?");
        grossSales = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("What is the commission rate?");
        commissionRate = input.nextDouble();
        dob = new Date(month, day, year);
        CommissionEmployee commissionEmployee = new 
            CommissonEmployee(firstName, lastName, socialNum, dob, 
                    grossSales, commissonRate);
        employees[i] = commissionEmployee; i++;

        inputInfo();
        System.out.print("What are the gross sales of the base plus 
                commission employee?");
        grossSales = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("What is the commission rate?");
        commissionRate = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("What is the base salary of the base plus 
                commission employee?");
        baseSalary = input.nextDouble();
        dob = new Date(month, day, year);
        BasePlusCommissionEmployee basePlusCommissionEmployee = new 
            BasePlusCommissionEmployee(firstName, lastName, 
                    socialNum, 
                    dob, grossSales, commissionRate, baseSalary);
        employees[i] = basePlusCommissionEmployee; i++;

        inputInfo();
        System.out.print("What is the wage of the hourly 
                employee?");
        wage = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("What are the hours of the hourly 
                employee?");
        hours = input.nextDouble();
        dob = new Date(month, day, year);
        HourlyEmployee hourlyEmployee = new 
            HourlyEmployee(firstName, 
                    lastName, socialNum, dob, wage, hours);
        employees[i] = hourlyEmployee; i++;
        System.out.println( "Employees processed polymorphically:\n" 
                );
        // generically process each element in array employees

        for ( Employee currentEmployee : employees )

        {

            System.out.println( currentEmployee ); // invokes 
            toString

                if(currentEmployee instanceof SalariedEmployee)
                {
                    SalariedEmployee employee = (SalariedEmployee) 
                        currentEmployee;
                    double oldBaseSalary = employee.getWeeklySalary();
                    employee.setWeeklySalary(4 * oldBaseSalary);
                    System.out.printf("earned: ", employee.earnings());
                }
            if(currentEmployee instanceof HourlyEmployee)
            {
                HourlyEmployee employee = (HourlyEmployee) currentEmployee;
                double oldBaseSalary = employee.getHours() * 
                    employee.getWage();
                employee.setWage(4 * oldBaseSalary);
                System.out.printf("earned: ", employee.getWage());
            }
            if(currentEmployee instanceof CommissionEmployee)
            {
                CommissionEmployee employee = (CommissonEmployee) 
                    currentEmployee;
                double oldBaseSalary = employee.getGrossSales() * 
                    employee.getCommissionRate();
                employee.setGrossSales(4 * oldBaseSalary);
                System.out.printf("earned: ", employee.getGrossSales());
            }
            // determine whether element is a BasePlusCommissionEmployee

            if ( currentEmployee instanceof BasePlusCommissionEmployee )

            {

                // downcast Employee reference to

                // BasePlusCommissionEmployee reference

                BasePlusCommissionEmployee employee =

                    ( BasePlusCommissionEmployee ) currentEmployee;



                double oldBaseSalary = employee.getBaseSalary();

                employee.setBaseSalary( 4 * oldBaseSalary );

                System.out.printf(

                        "new base salary with 10%% increase is: $%,.2f\n",

                        employee.getBaseSalary() );

            } // end if



            System.out.printf(

                    "earned $%,.2f\n\n", currentEmployee.earnings() );

        } // end for



        // get type name of each object in employees array

        for ( int j = 0; j < employees.length; j++ )

            System.out.printf( "Employee %d is a %s\n", j,

                    employees[ j ].getClass().getName() );

    } // end main

    static void inputInfo()
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String firstName;
        String lastName;
        String socialNum;
        double earnings;
        int month;
        int day;
        int year;
        double wage;
        double hours;
        double grossSales;
        double commissionRate;
        double baseSalary;
        Date dob = new Date();

        System.out.print("What is the first name of the employee?");
        firstName = input.next();
        System.out.print("What is the last name of the employee?");
        lastName = input.next();
        System.out.print("What is the social security number of the 
                employee?");
        socialNum = input.next();
        System.out.print("What month was the employee born?");
        month = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("What day was the employee born?");
        day = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("What year was the employee born?");
        year = input.nextInt();
    }


} // end class PayrollSystemTest
```

Comment: Quick guess: the `void inputInfo(); {` must not have the `;` in there. You only add a `;` when you call the method, not when you define it.

Comment: Move your method outside of the main and remove the semicolon

Comment: Remove `void inputInfo(); {` and the `}`. You can't define a method inside the `main`, and you can't access variables defined in `main` from a different method.

Comment: your code has disappeared...

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple issues in your code:

1) No closing brackets for Class and main method.

2) Method declaration should not end with **;** (`void inputInfo();`)

3) One method should not be declared inside other method, you call it but can't declare. (`inputInfo()` is declared in side main method)

4) Variables declared inside main method should won't be accessible to `inputInfo();`, because they will be private to main method.

5) In you want to call `inputInfo()` from `main` method, than `inputInfo()` should be declared as static.

6) Either all the variables should be declared as static if declaring class level or should be private to method, because static method can not use non-static method(s)/variable(s).

SO updated code will be like:

```
package test.file;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PayrollSystemTest {



  public static void main(final String args[]) {
    inputInfo();
  }

  static void inputInfo() {



    double baseSalary;

  double commissionRate;

  int day;

  Date dob = new Date();

  double earnings;

  String firstName;

  double grossSales;

  double hours;

  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

  String lastName;

  int month;

  String socialNum;

  double wage;

  int year;
    System.out.print("What is the first name of the employee?");
    firstName = input.next();
    System.out.print("What is the last name of the employee?");
    lastName = input.next();
    System.out.print("What is the social security number of the employee?");
    socialNum = input.next();
    System.out.print("What month was the employee born?");
    month = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("What day was the employee born?");
    day = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("What year was the employee born?");
    year = input.nextInt();
  }

}
```

Comment: When I put the method outside of the main method I get tons of error messages

Comment: this is what happens when I put the inputInfo method outside of main and then try to use it: non-static method inputInfo() cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: As mentioned in previous comment, I have already referred that issue in updated code. Refer that updated code. This is working code.

Comment: I would show you my updated entire code with your tips but i do not know how to copy and paste my code. Its too long to put into a "comment" and it won't let me put it as an edit to my original question. I have to hit ctrl k in front of every line and then it comes out looking weird

Comment: no i just got even more errors. ugh I wish i could just post my code. I don't understand why it wont let me

Comment: Prepend your code with four spaces. Do the same with the error messages. I editted a little, but I'm not sure if the strings that span over multiple lines were actually in your code or were a mistake when pasting.

Comment: However it would be more useful if you tried to find a small subset of your code that gives the same error. This code is too long. Read more here: how to write a [mcve].

Comment: This updated code is totally different from previous one. What is your employee class? This new code has so many other issues as well.

Comment: Got the issue, all the variables those are defined inside method inputInfo() , you need to put at class level as static (With static keyword), because these variables need to be accessed from both methods.

Answer (score 0):

There are three things wrong.

1) `main` is a method of the class and `inputInfo` is intended to be a method of the class.  You can't nest method definitions. You need the `}` to end the body of `main` before the `void inputInfo`. Add the closing brace, and make sure all the other braces pair up as intended.

2) All those data declarations look like they're supposed to be data members of the class, so need to be outside the declaration of the `main` method.

3) The semicolon after `void inputInfo()` incorrectly terminates the definition of inputInfo, which makes the following `{ … }` stuff outside of any method, and hence illegal.  Remove the semicolon.